# How to position the text inside a button?

Tags: html, css

I use an untypical image background inside a button. I need to make this text appear "higher" inside the button than the default (which is vertically centered). What I have to do?

CSS:

```
.button {
   width: 211px;
   height: 66px;

   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: white;

   background: url('../img/button.png') no-repeat;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
(...)
<button class="button">Get a quote</button>
```

Screen from browser:
 [image]

As you can see texts in buttons should be little bit higher then it is now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `padding-bottom`.

```
button{
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/8FE7t/)***

Answer (score 5):

The exact solution depends on what content exactly is placed into the button, but the general idea is:

- Use a `<button>` element
- Place a block element inside (a `<div>` will do fine)
- Give the block element bottom padding and put your text inside it

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/uNEKp/).

Alternatively, if you do not want to enlarge the button you could give the block element `position: relative` and a negative `top`.

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/pRjsT/).